# How do I convert a nvarchar to a uniqueidentifer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, uniqueidentifier, sqldatatypes, nvarchar

I have a table (`RPT.table1`) that contains data that was exported from an ArcGIS Online application.  One of the columns in the table (GlobalID) was exported as a `nvarchar(255)` datatype. I need to convert this column to a `uniqueidentifier` datatype before I insert this data into another table (`CFAdmin.table2`).

The values in the `GlobalID` column were once unique identifiers and already contain hyphens (`B4A6AA96-42DF-48D9-A3E0-4C7F88ED3E1D`).

I've tried using

```
ALTER TABLE RPT.table1 
ALTER COLUMN GlobalID uniqueidentifier;
```

and in an `INSERT INTO` statement

```
INSERT INTO CFAdmin.table2 (GlobalID)
    SELECT CAST(GlobalID AS uniqueidentifier)
    FROM RPT.table1;
```

For both methods I get an error

> Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

I'm relatively new to SQL Server and am guessing there is a pretty simple solution.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Your existing values contain at least one that cannot be converted. Select the rows where try_cast(GlobalID as uniqueidentifier) is null to find the unconvertible values. Then decide on how you want to proceed.

Comment: This should probably be the answer, not just a comment

Comment: Thanks @DRich .  You were right, I had an nonconvertible value.  Also learned about try_cast which is very handy. Thank you both!

Comment: + @SMor as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are there's an issue with your data, not with your code/syntax. There are probably values in the source table that are invalid as unique identifiers.  I would investigate by just looking at the data in your source table and trying to find the values that would cause the error.  See what this query returns:

```
Select GlobalID from RPT.table1 WHERE GlobalID NOT LIKE '________-____-____-____-____________'
```

(Those underscores blur together, so for the sake of being explicit: 8 underscores,  dash, 4 underscores, dash, 4 underscores, dash, 4 underscores, dash, 12 underscores)

And maybe check

```
Select GlobalID from RPT.table1 WHERE GlobalID IS NULL
```

Comment: This would only find values where the pattern of characters is valid. There are still lots of values that would not be a vaild uniqueidentifier that do match this pattern.

Comment: It's just a starting point.  I think @SMor's comment is a more rigorous solution.